# Extracting text from mysql server error []

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

If I issue an invalid sql statement in `pymysql` I get an exception as follows:

```
c.cursor.execute('select * fromd')
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'fromd' at line 1")
```

How would I get the textual error in the response?

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'fromd' at line 1"

Currently what I'm doing is:

```
try:
    c.cursor.execute('asdf')
except Exception as e:
    print (e)
```

But this gives me a "string tuple". Is there a way in this module to just get the error message itself?

Comment: use the 2nd element of e? `if len(e)>1: e[1] else: e` ? Or better - catch the specific `pymysql.err.ProgrammingError` to make sure it is always a 2-tuple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `e.args`:

```
try:
    self.cursor.execute(query)
except pymysql.err.ProgrammingError as e:
    error_msg = e.args[1]
    raise ConnectionError(error_msg)
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'asdf' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

You should catch the specific error:

```
import pymysql  
try: 
    raise pymysql.err.ProgrammingError(1064,"Bla")
except pymysql.err.ProgrammingError as prgError:
    if len(prgError.args)>1:
        print(prgError.args[1])  # might be not code + message but code only
    else:
        print(e)
except Exception as e:
    print (e)
```

Output:

```
Bla
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'ProgrammingError' object has no attribute 'msg'`

Comment: @DavidL yep - was testing it - seems I had the wrong doku. e.args[1] should work if the text was given - it might not.